# Debugging Maxima CAS Lisp code on Emacs

Tags: debugging, emacs, lisp, common-lisp, maxima

Is it possible to debug [Maxima CAS](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) Lisp code in Emacs?

It's a pain to use so many print statements all the time.

Comment: Best asked on the Maxima mailing list.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I frequent Maxima mailing list, I thought may be someone here might be aware of it.

Comment: Are you asking about running Maxima as Elisp, or about getting it running under a Common Lisp connected to Emacs through Slime?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Running it under common lisp connected to emacs through slime, I mean to do step by step debug of maxima lisp code.

Comment: Ok... so what have you tried, and what went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I've used two approaches over the years.

1. Run slime using the Maxima core file. See this email for how to do it

   http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mathematics.maxima.general/36029
2. Run Maxima but add code in the initialisation file to create a swank server then connect to that with `slime-connect`.

   http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mathematics.maxima.general/44533

Someone (Leo Butler, maybe?) on the list then suggested a neater approach than what's in that email. Unfortunately, my searching-fu has failed me and I can't find the conversation so I'll just paste what's in my `~/.maxima/swank.lisp` nowadays:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defvar *swank-asd*
    (car (directory #P"~/.emacs.d/elpa/slime*/swank.asd")))

  (when *swank-asd*
    (load *swank-asd*)
    (require :swank)))

(when (find-package :swank)

  (swank:create-server :port 56789 :dont-close t)
  ;; Hack to make "q" not kill Maxima outright. Only applies from console
  (in-package :maxima)
  (defvar *real-continue-function* (symbol-function 'continue))
  (setf (symbol-function 'continue)
        (lambda (&rest args)
          (let ((swank::*sldb-quit-restart* 'maxima::macsyma-quit))
            (apply *real-continue-function* args))))
  (format t "Swank loaded successfully"))
```

It starts by trying to load up swank from my Emacs directory (I install slime using Elpa). On success, or if swank was loaded anyway for some reason, it creates a server and then does the nifty "make the `q` key not really annoying" hack described in the second email.

Comment: will it help in debugging maxima's source code ? Is it not like running maxima on slime/emacs  rather than on terminal ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. My answer gives two different ways to run Maxima with slime connected. I thought that's what you wanted?

Comment: Yes I could guess that it will help me running maxima on slime but will it also help me setting breakpoints in maxima code and debug it also ?

Comment: If you mean code written in the Maxima language then, no, this won't really help. Add print statements and factor your code into lots of little bits that you can check separately. Also, Maxima's language isn't really designed as a general purpose language: use lisp or something else for large computations.

Comment: all the functions accessible in maxima pl can be directly used in lisp with $ appended. So now it is debug-able? I think not !!